# Local "boundary comparison principle" for harmonic functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, soft-question, elliptic-pde

Let $u$ be a positive solution of the elliptic equation $\mathcal Lu = 0$  on $B^+_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $u$ vanishes continuously on $\{x_n = 0\}$. To fix ideas, we may take $\mathcal L = - \Delta$, ie $u$ harmonic.

Then we can prove the comparison principle stated in STEP 1 below ([Caffarelli](http://ins.sjtu.edu.cn/files/paper/20170525145746_obstacle-long.pdf), 1998 p. 40):

$$u\big|_{B^+_{1/2}} \le M.$$

I've some questions on the proof below (PROOF OF STEP 1).

- In particular, what does the **(c)** observation mean? What does the author mean by $M>M_0$ large enough? What is the "absurde assumption" that will lead to a contradiction?
- Why after proving that

> "if $M \ge M_0$ large, we can construct a sequence of points, $X_k$ all contained in $B^+_{3/4}$, $X_k → \{x_n = 0\}$, and such that $u(X_k)$ goes to $+\infty$"

do we get that the proof of STEP 1 is complete?

[image]

Comment: Iterate and consider a sequence of nested balls $B_{1/2^{n+1}}\subset B_{1/2^{n}}$, I presume?

Comment: @leomonsaingeon My mistake: I meant the $(c)$ step.

Comment: By Item (b), if $u(X_0)=M$, for $X_0\in B_{1/2}^+$ is large then one must have $x_n(X_0)$ small.  This should yield the contradiction,   I'm not sure why the points $X_k$ are said to lie in $B_{3/4}^+$ and not $B_{1/2}^+$.  Is this this is because the balls are open?

Comment: Something must be wrong in the formulation. If $u$ is harmonic and positive in $B_1$, and if it vanishes at some interior point (here for $x_n=0$), then $u\equiv0$.

Comment: @DenisSerre You're right. There is a typo in the first line: the function is harmonic on $B^+_1$, i.e. the part of the ball above $\{x_n=0\}$.